# How to listen changes in routing Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I subscribed on changes in routing:

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.language = params['id'];
    });

    console.log(this.language);
  }
```

But when I change route path by click link I can not see `console.log(this.language);`. It is not displayed. There are not errors.

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: just move `console.log` inside `params=>{...} function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subscribe` is asynchronous. The `console.log()` may be called before this `this.language = params['id'];` statement is called (We won't know the flow because it is asynchronous).

You should put `console.log(this.language);` in the function inside `subscribe`:

```
this.subscription = this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.language = params['id'];
  console.log(this.language);
});
```

This will make sure that `console.log(this.language);` is called right after `this.language = params['id'];`, since both statement are synchronous.

Comment: @Daniel try `console.log(params)` does your `params` variable even have an `id` property?

Comment: @Daniel Look in your appModule where you register your path urls, does it have something like this: `/{yourUri}/:id` ... In order to get the `params['id']`, your path url should have this `:id` part

Comment: In routing I have: `{ path: 'language/:id', component: LanguageComponent },`

Comment: `console.log(params);` is empty object when component is initialized

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe method is used to subscribe to messages that are sent to an observable.This is ASYNC function , So you have to print  "this.language" value inside subscribe

```
 public ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.language = params['id'];
            console.log(this.language);
        });


      }
```

Comment: May be problem in routing: I have path URL: `http://localhost:3000/#/language/en` and it changed.